# How to package go project for homebrew

Tags: go, package, formula, homebrew

We're developing [runscripts](https://github.com/runscripts/runscripts) and try to support something like `brew install runscripts`.

It's written in golang and have some dependencies which required to `go get`. Now I have no idea to write the Formula to setup GOPATH and run `go get`. Our project can be compiled into an binary but we need `run --init` to install it.

Can anyone helps to give an example about a homebrew Formula of go project?

Comment: Docker is in Go: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/docker.rb

Comment: Thanks @Matt. I have read `docker.rb` but it's a little complicated. We just need to `go get` the dependencies and run a command to install it.

Answer (score 5):

Fork [homebrew](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core), look at the content of Library/Formula/consul.rb. You don't need to manually generate all the resources. Use [homebrew-go-resources](https://github.com/samertm/homebrew-go-resources). A more complete intro could be found [here](https://docs.brew.sh/Formula-Cookbook#specifying-gems-python-modules-go-projects-etc-as-dependencies).

Answer (score 1):

I have refer to [termshare.rb](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/3c6951ca3072c76af19d096e1332c31de07426c6/Library/Formula/termshare.rb) and it seems we can simply `go get` and homebrew will handle anything about `GOPATH` for us.

That's great and I think my problem is solved.

Comment: The original link is archived (read-only) but it still has value, so I didn't want to edit it.  However, this is the current link to the termshare.rb formula:  https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/termshare.rb

Answer (score 1):

The best I could find is how `docker-swarm` is added to brew: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/4c6857b0e337b2d5afd49dcf7209b6b5091709f4/Library/Formula/docker-swarm.rb

It's relatively clean and simple to follow.

Answer (score 1):

You can use goreleaser to generate the formula automatically: https://goreleaser.com/customization/homebrew/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible work around creating a `build` directory within the checkout as the `GOPATH`:

```
...
def install
    system "mkdir -p build/src"
    system "ln -s `pwd` build/src/repo"
    system "GOPATH=`pwd`/build go get repo/mytool"
    bin.install "build/bin/mytool"
    ...
end
...
```

Comment: Very curious why this was downvoted. It ended up working for me.